# html css How to make input field change size without pushing text to next line

Tags: css, input, size, field

How to make input field change size without pushing text to next line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDX30.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is going to be using `display: flex`, for more details read [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on MDN.

Getting the labels the right width will require a bit of tweaking on your part, I've used `.fieldGroup label { width: 10vw }` as a loose value. Best is to use a pixel (`px`) value which will very much depend on the font family and size

```css
/* BASIC RESET - not relvant to answer */ body { font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }

.fieldGroup {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.fieldGroup:not(:last-of-type) { margin-bottom: 1rem }

.fieldGroup label { width: 10vw }
.fieldGroup input { flex-grow: 1 }
```

```html
<form style="padding: 2rem">
  <div class="fieldGroup">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name&hellip;">
  </div>
  <div class="fieldGroup">
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail&hellip;">
  </div>
  <div class="fieldGroup">
    <label>Really long label here to easily test wrapping</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="???">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` in CSS

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <b>With Flex:</b>
  <div class="flex">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input />
  </div>
  
  <br />
  
  <b>Without Flex:</b>
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You almost got it right, the inputs need to fill the remaining space so that label and input together are 100% width